# Issue with microsoft WCF web service reference provider in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, service-reference

I have a WCF service exposed both synchronous and asynchronous methods. When I try to add microsoft WCF web service reference provider in my .net core 2 application, I am showing only methodnameAsync methods. I am not able to see methodname methods.

If I add this service reference in regular Console application, it is showing both synchronous and asynchronous methods.

I google about this and few are telling to change the setting in wizard like [Click for Image](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/435080).

But I can not see any such option in my .net core2 application wizard.

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you please elaborate the steps yo are following to add service reference.

Comment: @DipteeH 

1. Right Click on Project
2. Add => Connected Service
3. Click  Microsoft WCF Web Service Refernce Provider
4. Provide URI => Click Go
5. Enter Namespace
6. Click Next=> Click Finish
that's it.